# Quorum Questions For An FCI And AlwaysOn in a WSFC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, clustering, high-availability

I was reading the white paper on FCI + AlwaysOn as well as several other resources on quorum voting differences in Windows Server 2008 and 2014 and had 3 questions.

**1-** Will giving a node in the WSFC that is a read only Replica a vote in WSFC let it vote on the FCI quorum or is the 'vote' in WSFC for something else?  That part I'm not clear on.  The host is only part of an AlwaysOn replica set and in the same WSFC as the FCI, but it is not part of the FCI.  It currently shows as having a vote in WSFC.

Will it count as a vote for any FCI's we have on that WSFC or it will be ignored?
Cluster info:

```
Get-ClusterNode  | fl Nodename, Nodeweight
    NodeName   : Server1
    NodeWeight : 1

    NodeName   : Server2
    NodeWeight : 1

    NodeName   : Server3
    NodeWeight : 1

Get-ClusterQuorum
Cluster              QuorumResource
-------              --------------
Cluster1      Cluster Disk 2
```

**2-** Will a long failover (let's say 30-50 seconds) cause a service shut down in 2012 due to the quorum disk NOT being online during that period if the server is turned off/disabled for some reason, leaving us with only 2 or 1 vote(s)?  In other words is WSFC intelligent enough to know that a Quorum is a shared FCI resource in which the host is currently failing over, so temporary ignore the fact that it's down.  Sometimes an FCI failover takes a long time on Windows 2008 in our environment.

**3-** Will any FCI have a issue if it only has 1 vote?  Let's say we have a quorum and a 2nd node and both the quorum and 2nd node are down at the moment due to failover or a disk issue.  Would that 1 vote then say it has 50% or less and turn off services?

Edit: I could also ask this differently: Is the vote a *total available number of votes in the entire WSFC or is it just **currently available** nodes?  I feel it's the *total number of all nodes regardless of current state hence why we need to stop votes from the DR sites often but I wanted clarification.  Thanks!

Current topology is simple:

```
    2 node multi tenant cluster (2 active instances on 2 nodes).  
This will be updated to meet our requirements of n+1 so we will have 3 nodes.

    1 read only AlwaysOn read only replica server with no automatic failover

    1 quorum disk on the FCI as a witness
```

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, you don't need the Disk (Or you need to remove the vote from the RO Replica).  Basically, you want an odd number of votes so in a 2-1 situation someone has Quorum.  As it is now, you could have a 2-2 situation.

Comment: Hi Chad, thank you. That's definitely 1 of the questions I had.  So to confirm, a member of the WSFC that is not part of a FCI can have a vote assigned regardless.  Got it.

Comment: This is fully dependent upon the version of windows being used. If you're using 2012R2 then dynamic witness will play its' role and this should be fine the way it is. If you're using anything lower than WS2012R2 there is no dynamic witness and I would go with what @ChadMattox said.

Comment: Albeit if there were on separate subnets you could also use the now deprecated "lowerquorumprioritynodeid" setting...